# How to set expiry time for all Ignite caches?

Tags: xml, spring, scala, ignite

I am starting ignite by a specific configuration. In that configuration, I specified expiration policy. But expiration is not working. When I specified a cache name in that property, it is working fine.

I added configuration like below

```
<property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
   </property>
```

But this is not working for all caches,

When I tried config like below it is working,

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                     <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                      <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
                        <constructor-arg>
                          <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                            <constructor-arg value="SECONDS"/>
                            <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                          </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                      </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="name" value="test"/>
                    <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                </bean>
```

Here the cache "test" is expiring correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an `abstract` CacheConfiguration bean containing `<expiryPolicyFactory>`, and inherit (using `parent="beanName"`) all of cache cfg's from that bean. That's how it usually done in Spring:

```
<bean id="expireCache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
        <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                    <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean parent="expireCache">
                <property name="name" value="test"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
            </bean>
...
```

Abstract bean should be put on the top level alongside with IgniteConfiguration bean.

Comment: Here the expiration is set only to "test" cache. I need to set expiration for all caches. Or whether i can specify the cache name dynamically ?

Comment: You can do that for all caches you create. Yes, you can specify cache name dynamically. See the docs: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-template

Comment: So can you edit above comment as answer , Then it is useful for other people