# Is it possible to set expiry time using Apache Ignite in C++?

Tags: c++, ignite

I am using the C++ thin client API and I want to have the data deleted from the cache after 5 minutes. I am connecting to ignite through docker and using the persistence storage. In the documentation for the C++ libraries, I cannot find anything relating to "expiry" and I tried adding the expiry option into the config xml file that my docker container reads in, but that didn't seem to work either. I put data into the cache and checked for the data after 5 minutes (I also checked 10, 20, 30 minutes later) and the data was still there.

Here is my config xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

    <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="name" value="Default_Region" />
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
        <property name="ipFinder">
          <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
          <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
            <property name="addresses">
              <list>
                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47502</value>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>

  </bean>


  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">

    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
      <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" factory-method="factoryOf">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
            <constructor-arg value="MINUTES"/>
            <constructor-arg value="5"/>
          </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>

  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you show the full cache configuration inside the ignite.xml?

Comment: I edited my post to include the full config file.

Comment: I can't see your caches here, how do you create them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the c++ thin client doesn't support this feature at the moment.

I think you could either define a cache with expiration completely on the server-side or to define only a cache template https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-template with expiry policy and use it from a client.

Comment: How do you define a cache with expiration entirely on the server-side? I thought putting the expiration in the xml file on the server side did that. Is that not the case? My docker instance is reading in the xml, not the C++ code.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's right. I was thinking that you were looking for a dynamic TTL cache configuration using a c++ thin client.  Java and .NET clients can do this with cache#withExpiryPolicy method for example.

Comment: Does that mean even if I define it on the server side it won't work (like I'm doing now)? Or is there something else I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Comment: No, it should work, please have a look at the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703010/how-to-set-expiry-time-for-all-ignite-caches

Comment: More precisely, you need to specify the <property name="cacheConfiguration"> inside your ignite's bean, also it's better to remove your work and persisted dirs before applying the changes

Comment: Okay good to know that I can do that. I'm confused about where to put it though. I followed the example in the link you sent, but I don't understand where I need to put the <property name="cacheConfiguration"> part. Where do I put it based on the xml file I have above?

Comment: Please, check this file https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/platforms/dotnet/Apache.Ignite.Core.Tests/Config/cache-query.xml
The cache configuration should be set under the IgniteConfiguration and a cache with name "cache" should be created on startup.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the <property name="cacheConfiguration"> in the wrong spot, but I got it working and it's doing exactly what I wanted!